# why does adding a printf("A") make my code run, and removing it makes it crash

Tags: c, runtime-error

I have the following code in C:

```
while(tempNode!=NULL) {
    int pos = pathNodesCount-1-i;
    pathNodes[pos] = tempNode;
    //printf("A");
    euclidianLength += tempNode->g;
    i = i+1;
    tempNode = tempNode->parent;
}
```

if I leave the `printf("A")` statement commented out, and then compile and run my code, I will get an "application stopped running" Windows error. If I uncomment the `printf("A")` line, recompile and run, the application will run to its end (printing "A" to the console along the way). Why?

The environment is:

- Windows 7 32bit
- MinGW32 20120426 (and I've added MSys 1.0)
- Eclipse Juno for C/CPP

== UPDATE

I've tracked my error. I won't post the exact code as it is too long, but it was a case of creating a char array, and then adding characters at wrong indexes. Something like this:

```
int otherCrap() {
    char* c = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<13; i++) {
        c[i]='a';
    }
    c[15] = '\0';
    printf("A");
    printf(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Fixing the thing so that the chars were placed inside the array only at existing indexes, and also ading '\0' char as the last element in the array fixed the issue. However I'm still not clear as to why, when the code was bad, adding a printf('A') before printing the char array didn't result in a runtime error. From the answers received so far I am to understand that this falls under "undefined behavior".

Comment: A wild guess - stack corruption. Are you sure `pos` has a correct value?

Comment: If your program is multi-threaded it could be a race condition that is alleviated because of the extra time in the `printf` call. Otherwise it could be some stack problem. Have you run in a debugger to make sure the indexing is not out of range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because some error in the code causes undefined behavior. Having the code then appear to "work" in the presence of a `printf()` is fine.

That indexing logic counting backwards looks scary; verify that it's correct. Print the index before using it, compare to the known size of the `pathNodes` array, if you have one. Beware of the index turning negative or overrunning the capacity of `pathNodes`.

Comment: Well, that's what I was trying to do: print the index in the scary loop, because I also though something bad was happening with it. And once I added a printf("%d\n",whateverVariable), I noticed that everything worked ok (and indexes were ok). I then reduced the printf to printf("A") and it still worked, and I don't get why...

Comment: @ShivanDragon - the index was my guess, too. OK, as it's fine, run the  test again and keep an eye on `tempNode = tempNode->parent;`. Also, as the issue is easily reproducible, why don't you catch the bug, using a debugger?

Comment: @Kiril Kirov: thanks for the input. I'd love to use a debugger, but I don't know how. Yes, it's stupid, I'm a noob, sorry. I've tried debugging with Eclipse, but I've noticed that it works only when the code manages to run to it's end. If the code will end up in "application stopped unexpectedly" the debugger will never stop at my break points. But that's another issue. At any rate, I've found my error, and will add it as an update to the question.

Comment: @ShivanDragon - it's not a big deal you can't use a debugger. At the beginning, it's kinda strange, but knowing how to use a debugger is priceless and it's worth spending some time on learning how to use it.

Comment: @KirilKirov I completly agree with you and intend to do that next. This is just my 5th day of C. At any rate, I was hoping that my experience in Java will help with the learning, but in fact it does not, C's way of doing some things is totally different.